# Change in SATA Configuration

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, sata, ahci

I have a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. So due to slow performance of Windows I changed my **bios SATA Configuration from IDE to AHCI** and I observed that my laptop **boots quickly in Ubuntu than the previous boot**. So my question is that even I didn't see any errors due to changed settings but will a error arise in future?

Comment: It also works faster with disk access ;-) It is not related to any OS. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problems for Ubuntu if you change IDE mode to AHCI.

AHCI mode is faster not only at boot time.

Fore details about AHCI see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface